# Use wifi and ethernet simultaneously on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have noticed recently that during downloading or updating games in my Steam library, I can somehow manage to double the speed at which this occurs by unplugging my ethernet cable, waiting a few seconds, and then plugging it back in again.  This allows me to utilise both my wifi connection and my ethernet connection (to the same router) at the same time.  However, as soon as the Steam operation has completed, Windows (I believe) defaults back to only using my ethernet connection and disables the wifi.  I would like to know if there is any way to stop Windows from doing this - without the use of third-party applications - to allow me to use both connections simultaneously, or if it's just a weird thing that Steam does.

Thanks in advance,

James.

Edit:  It turns out that it's not just steam that does this thing with the internet; Nvidia GeForce Experience and some other apps manage to sustain a connection over ethernet and WiFi at the same time, but when the download is complete, Windows (I guess) turns off WiFi connectivity and defaults to ethernet.

Answer (score 10):

I am studying Computer Science at a university where I have 100mbps ethernet and 100mbps wifi available in my dorm. I have always been using the ethernet for everything as its way more stable when downloading games than wifi which fluctuates a lot. I wanted to combine both of them to increase my speed and looked online and found that i have to make a network bridge so that both the connections get combined. The steps are as below:

1. Go to Control Panel and click Network and Internet.
2. Click Network and Sharing Center.
3. On the left column click change adapter settings.
4. Select both the connections and right click to see options. Click network bridge.
5. Windows will automatically make a network bridge and you are done.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Where there is throttling on the server side, it may be possible to increase download speed by opening **additional connections**. The speed increase you observed is likely because you've opened a second download thread, not because you're getting throughput over Ethernet (which should be the maximum speed of the router) and WiFi (which may be slower, particularly far from the router).

You state specifically "without the use of third-party applications". In that case, you're out of luck. Microsoft Edge and IE do not offer multiple connections for a single download, though you can try this [MS fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282402/how-do-i-configure-internet-explorer-to-download-more-than-two-files-a) to increase number of *downloads*, as opposed to connections. There are add-on application managers, some installed as extensions to a browser, but they are all third-party tools. There might even be a browser with such a manger built into it, but, again, that's a third-party app.

You may reconsider and try a third-party download manager, such as [Free Download Manager (FDM)](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/). In the screenshot below, the `Low` setting allows up to 15 simultaneous connections to one site, five connections each to three sites, or any other combination up to the total of 15 connections.

[image: Free Download Manager multiple connections]

*Caveats:*

- Not all sites allow multiple connections. In those cases, there will be no speed increase over direct download through a browser.
- Though FDM appeared clean, check *any* downloaded application at [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload). Some applications also include adware or malware, .

Comment: "without the use of third-party applications"

Comment: Ok, even if I can't use both connection methods on Windows normally, can you explain why Steam is allowed to use both methods (which can be seen in task manager that Ethernet and Wi-Fi are operating, and at roughly the same speed at that)?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how Steam works.